# SMTP OAUTH2 and outlook / MS Exchange

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, smtp, office365, phpmailer

I use laravel socialite to auth microsoft account (with microsoft entra id). After I received user token, refresh token and emial I want to authorize smtp. I try to connect with:

(for example purpose I prepare a PHPmailer example)

```
$token = 'access token from api response';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.office365.com'; //I also check smtp-mail.outlook.com
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = 'my-email........com';
    $mail->Password   = base64_encode("user=" . $mail->Username . "^Aauth=Bearer " . $token . "^A^A");
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
```

Unfortunately, I cannot connect and send mail after this. Connecting Debug returns some like this:

```
2024-02-08 17:05:04     SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2024-02-08 17:05:04     CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO test
2024-02-08 17:05:04     SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-WA2P291CA0031.outlook.office365.com Hello [2a01:112f:6a3:7000:7f12:6315:d427:e5a7]
                                          250-SIZE 157286400
                                          250-PIPELINING
                                          250-DSN
                                          250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
                                          250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
                                          250-8BITMIME
                                          250-BINARYMIME
                                          250-CHUNKING
                                          250 SMTPUTF8
2024-02-08 17:05:04     SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2024-02-08 17:05:04     CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-02-08 17:05:04     SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2024-02-08 17:05:04     SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.%
```

In Thunderbir I see my account connecting on ssl and other host (on the first example I try starttls and 587 because here I see that parameters: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-for-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040) so I also check it:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
```

But in that settings all looks like connection timeout :/

Do you know what I do wrong? Thanks!

--edit1
I think I have something wrong with

```
base64_encode("user=" . $mail->Username . "^Aauth=Bearer " . $token . "^A^A")
```

in the documentation it is also used this way, but only when I do
[image]

I get the same effect as in the example. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here? Maybe I should change something else with the username?

Comment: It strikes me as odd that you're using PHPMailer with Laravel, when Laravel has a good mail client built in. Anyway, in your first example it's failing before it even tries to authenticate, so I suggest you set `SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_LOWLEVEL` to show more info during the auth phase. Beyond that, know that Azure's OAuth support is very tricky; [read this thread](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/2988).

Comment: I can't provide all the code from laravel, and phpmailer is the easiest to do the same (in laravel's smtp the error is identical). I just know that it is difficult and that is why I need help. Thank you!  ;)

Comment: I add details to task, can you look ;)

Comment: Please link to the documentation that you are basing this on.

Comment: Hello, thanks for response. I found documentation here:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth